# Is it possible to change 'Link to' in all images in all articles?

Tags: images, media, links

After some update, they all changed to none. Need to change to 'Media file'. Can I do it once and for all pictures in all articles?

[image]

I see in the text of article difference between images with Link To none and Media File:

```
<!-- Media File -->
<a href="... url ..."><img class="alignnone wp-image-936 size-full" src="... url ..." alt="Боракай" width="1000" height="586" /></a>

<!-- None -->
<img class="alignnone wp-image-936 size-full" src="... url ..." alt="Боракай" width="1000" height="586" />
```

So, it is an `a` tag. I suppose some regex applied to all articles would help.

Comment: Do you want to change the default value for that select field, or change the value set for images already linked in articles?

Comment: I think they mean the ones already linked. However unless I'm mistaken, that's just stored in the post content itself, not separately in the database associated with the image or anything.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż thanks for the help! want to 'change the value set for images already linked in articles'

Comment: @tmdesignedthanks for the help! Yes, the difference in the post content. Updated question text. It's already useful. Now need to find an approach to update all articles so that all images would become links